# What is the difference between use case of constructor vs init to set the value during object construction?

Tags: c#

An init-only setter assigns a value to the property or the indexer element only during object construction. What is the difference between use case of constructor vs init to set the value during object construction?

Sample 1:

```
public class Person
{
   private string _myName;

   public Person(string myName)
   {
      _myName= myName;
   }

   public string Name => _myName;
}
```

Sample 2:

```
public class Person
{
   private string _myName;

   public string Name
     {
         get { _myName; }
         init { _myName= value; }
     }
}
```

Sample 3 (ignore this sample because it is the same as Sample 2):

```
public class Person
{
   private string _myName;

   public string Name
     {
         get => _myName; 
         init => _myName= value;
     }
}
```

Comment: Constructor allows you to create the object with values as arguments... init allows you to set the value after creating an instance

Comment: The biggest difference in general: error handling is limited in constructor. You can’t return errors, you can only throw exceptions. This may not be suitable always. The object won’t exist if you throw. Otherwise it’s just a case of one or two method calls.

Comment: In c# you do not need write these lots of code to set. Just where initialize property define it like : `Public string Name { get{}; set{}; }`

Comment: And remember if you want to have an constructor method which get arguments that set their properties, you can define a constructor Whit arguments. And can define any number of constructors that you want. Sometimes your variables should be defined or change during process of calculation. You want to change state of object in the middle of programme like. So you change variables value without defining new class. Good luck

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen "error handling is limited in constructor." - How is it any different for an `init` property? You can't do anything but throw an exception there either.

Comment: @Jawad - I'd be slightly more strict on your definition as `init` values can only be set immediately after the constructor in an object initializer. For example, `new Foo("Hello") { Y = "World" }`, but not `var foo = new Foo("Hello"); foo.Y = "World";`.

Comment: @Hamed_gibago We should be preferring and recommending immutability instead of mutable objects.

Comment: What's the point of using string interpolation `$"{_myName}"` when `_myName` is a `string`?

Comment: @Enigmativity - I removed the string interpolation now

Comment: @Hamed_gibago That's completely unrelated to my point.

Comment: @Dai Ah, true, I was talking more in general way from an init method, but this was property. You are correct

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen C# does not have "init methods", only init properties.

Comment: A constructor parameter is mandatory. A property setter is optional.

Comment: @Hamed_gibago this is about as bad as you could write these things. If you have get and set without anything it. Just use fields. And like others have said, you probably won't want everything to be mutable, so you want to remove the set entirely in most cases to ensure you always get what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The main differences and similarities are described in this table: <sub>(including my editorializing...)</sub>

|  | Constructor parameter | `init` property |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Since | C# 1.0 | [C# 9.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/init) |
| Are required / Has hard guarantees about being present | Yes | No |
| Self-documenting | [Since C# 4.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) | Yes |
| Can overwrite `readonly` fields | Yes | Yes |
| Suitable for | Required and optional values | Optional values |
| Ease of reflection | Just use `ConstructorInfo` | Horrible |
| Supported by [MEDI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) | Yes | No |
| [Breaks `IDisposable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409918/object-initializer-and-dispose-when-property-can-throw-exception) | No | Yes |
| Class knows init order | Yes | No |
| Ergonomics when subclassing | Tedious | Decent |

The downsides of `init` are mostly inherited from the downsides of C#'s object-initializer expressions which still have numerous issues (in the footnote).

As for when you should vs. shouldn't:

- Don't use `init` properties for required values - use a constructor parameter instead.
- *Do* use `init` properties for nonessential, non-required, or otherwise optional values that when set via individual properties do not invalidate the object's state.

---

- In short, `init` properties make it *slightly easier* to initialize nonessential properties in immutable types - however they also make it easier to shoot yourself in the foot if you're using `init` for *required* members instead of using a constructor parameter, *especially* C# 8.0 nullable-reference-types (as there's no guarantees that a non-nullable reference-type property will ever be assigned).
- In terms of guidance:

  - If your `class` is not immutable, or at least does not employ immutable-semantics on certain properties then you don't need to use `init` on those properties.
  - If it's a `struct` then don't use `init` properties at all, due to all the small details in `struct` copy behavior.
  - In my opinion (not shared by everyone else), I recommend you consider an optional (could also be nullable) constructor parameter or an entire different constructor overload instead of `init` properties given the problems I feel they have and lack of any real advantages.

---

Footnote: Problems with C# object-initializer syntax, inherited by `init` properties:

- [Breaks debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768906/cannot-identify-the-property-which-throw-exception-when-using-object-initializer): Even in C# 9, if any line of the initializer throws an exception then the exception's `StackTrace` will be the same line as the `new` statement instead of the line of the sub-expression that caused the exception.
- [Breaks `IDisposable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409918/object-initializer-and-dispose-when-property-can-throw-exception): if a property-setter (or initialization expression) throws an exception and *if* the type implements `IDisposable` then the newly created instance will not be disposed-of, even though the constructor completed (and the object is fully initialized as far as the CLR is concerned).

Comment: Great answer and much better then mine. Thanks for the summary.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start off by looking at the anatomy of an `init` property.

Take these two simple examples:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
}
```

Let's look at the IL differences between the two:

```
.class nested public auto ansi beforefieldinit Foo extends [System.Runtime]System.Object
{
    .method public hidebysig specialname instance string get_Name () cil managed { ... }
    .method public hidebysig specialname instance void set_Name (string 'value') cil managed { ... }

    .property instance string Name()
    {
        .get instance string Foo::get_Name()
        .set instance void Foo::set_Name(string)
    }
}

.class nested public auto ansi beforefieldinit Bar extends [System.Runtime]System.Object
{
    .method public hidebysig specialname instance string get_Name () cil managed { ... }
    .method public hidebysig specialname instance void modreq([System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit) set_Name (string 'value') cil managed { ... }

    .property instance string Name()
    {
        .get instance string Bar::get_Name()
        .set instance void modreq([System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit) Bar::set_Name(string)
    }
}
```

The only difference between the two is the `modreq([System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit)`.

Both `Foo` and `Bar` implement a `public` getter & setter, just that `Bar` has a special `IsExternalInit` attribute on the `public` setter.

The difference is compiler controlled. The only time that an `init` property can be set is during construction or within the [object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers).

Let's look at a more complicated example:

```
public class Electricity
{
    private const double _amps = 4.2;
    public double Amps => _amps;
    
    private readonly double _power;
    public double Power => _power;
    
    private double _volts;
    public double Volts
    {
        get => _volts;
        init
        {
            _volts = value * 2;
            _power = value * _amps;
            //_amps = 99.0; // Not allowed! Can only be set by direct assignment - effectively prior to construction!
        }
    }
    
    public Electricity(double volts)
    {
        this.Volts = volts * 5;
        _power = 9.2;
        //_amps = 42.0; // Not allowed! Can only be set by direct assignment - effectively prior to construction!
    }
    
    public void Danger()
    {
        //_amps = 0.0; // Not allowed! Can only be set by direct assignment - effectively prior to construction!
        //_power = 0.0; // Not allowed! Can only be set in constructor or init
        //this.Volts = -1.0; // Not allowed! Can only be set in constructor or init
        _volts = 0.0; // Allowed!
    }
}
```

With this, I can create an instance with this code:

```
Electricity e = new Electricity(1.0) { Volts = 2.0 };
```

Now this effectively calls `new Electricity(1.0)` to create the instance of the class, and, since it is the only constructor, I am forced to call it with a parameter for `volts`. Note that, inside the constructor, I can call `this.Volts = volts * 5;`.

Before the assignment to `e` the code in the initializer block is called. It's just assigning `2.0` to `Volts` - it is the direct equivalent of `e.Volts = 2.0;` had we not declared `Volts` with an `init` setter.

The result is that by the time `e` gets assigned the constructor and the call to set `Volts` have both completed.

Now let's try to make this `Electricity` code more robust. Let's say that I wanted to be able to set any two properties and have the code compute the third.

A naïve and incorrect implementation would be this:

```
public class Electricity
{
    public double Volts { get; private set; }
    public double Amps { get; private set; }
    public double Watts => this.Volts * this.Amps;

    public Electricity(double volts, double amps)
    {
        this.Volts = volts;
        this.Amps = amps;
    }

    public Electricity(double volts, double watts)
    {
        this.Volts = volts;
        this.Amps = watts / this.Volts;
    }

    public Electricity(double amps, double watts)
    {
        this.Amps = amps;
        this.Volts = watts / this.Amps;
    }
}
```

But, of course, this doesn't compile because the three constructors signatures are the same.

But we can use `init` to make an object that works no matter what properties I set (with the exception of `Watts` in the example below).

```
public class Electricity
{
    private readonly double? _volts = null;
    private readonly double? _amps = null;
    private readonly double? _watts = null;

    public double Volts
    {
        get => _volts ?? 0.0;
        init
        {
            _volts = value;
            if (_amps.HasValue)
            {
                _watts = _volts * _amps;
            }
            else if (_watts.HasValue)
            {
                _amps = _watts / _volts;
            }
        }
    }

    public double Amps
    {
        get => _amps ?? 0.0;
        init
        {
            _amps = value;
            if (_volts.HasValue)
            {
                _watts = _volts * _amps;
            }
            else if (_watts.HasValue)
            {
                _volts = _watts / _amps;
            }
        }
    }

    public double Watts
    {
        get => _watts ?? 0.0;
        init
        {
            _watts = value;
            if (_volts.HasValue)
            {
                _amps = _watts / _volts;
            }
            else if (_amps.HasValue)
            {
                _volts = _watts / _amps;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can now do this:

```
var electricities = new[]
{
    new Electricity() { Amps = 2.0, Volts = 3.0 },
    new Electricity() { Watts = 2.0, Volts = 3.0 },
    new Electricity() { Amps = 2.0, Watts = 3.0 },
    new Electricity(),
};
```

This gives me:

[image: electricities]

So, the net result is that constructors are compulsory, but `init` properties are optional yet must be used at the time of construction before any reference is passed back to the calling code.

Comment: "But we can use init to make an object that works no matter what properties I set" - but this is demonstrably false: I can do `new Electricity()` and never set any of the properties. In which case _all_ properties's getters will throw an exception because they all assume non-null `double?` field values - which is a bad class design. I feel a better approach is to use constructor overloads, but use distinct value-types to represent each quantity (i.e. _dimensional-analysis_) so the ctor overloads will compile fine and using distinct types also mean you can't assign Amps to Volts and vice-versa.

Comment: @Dai - Sorry, I didn't intend to write 100% robust production code, but only enough to demonstrate the principle. I have improved the code to avoid the problem with unset values.

Comment: No need to apologize! (I didn't downvote you btw, I upvoted you just now, in fact)

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to allow readonly properties that you know that will have a written value only during initialization of the object, but after the initialization the value cannot be written.

If you define a `set` method instead of `init`, the value can be written any time during the object's life span.

This allows you to initialize a property without having to pass it directly to the constructor as parameter.

For example:

```
class A
{
    public int X { get; init;} 
}
```

Allows this:

```
A a = new A() 
{
    X = 3,
};
```

And trying to write to `X` after that, won't compile:

```
a.X = 5;
```

gives a compilation error:

```
CS8852  Init-only property or indexer 'A.X' can only be assigned in an object initializer, or on 'this' or 'base' in an instance constructor or an 'init' accessor.
```

If you don't use `init`, and use `set` instead, your object can be written any time.

If you define a readonly property without the `init` method, you can still initialize the property inside a constructor, but then you have to pass a parameter to the constructor. So the decision to use `init` depends more of you code styling and where do you hold the parameters for the initialized field, and whether you prefer to pass it to a constructor or not.

Notice that this has nothing to do with field access. If `init` is defined as `public`, then it is possible to initialize it from outside of the class. It can also be declared `private` or `protected` and then it can be accessed from the class or deriving classes only respectively.