# Order of assignments in object-initializer when using nested objects

Tags: c#, object-initializers

I have the following code creating an instance of `Root` using an object-initializer:

```
var r = new Root { Person = new Person { Age = 20, Name = "Hans" } };
```

From [Is there any benefit of using an Object Initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842371/is-there-any-benefit-of-using-an-object-initializer) I know if we´d have only the inner object `Person` this was translated to something like this:

```
var p = new Person();
p.Age = 20;
p.Name = 20;
```

What I wonder is how does this affect the nested objects in my first example? Is `Person` completely created and than assigned to the new instance of `Root` or is this merely translated to something like this:

```
var r = new Root();
r.Person = new Person();
r.Person.Age = 20;          // this would call the Persons getter
r.Person.Name = "Hans";     // this would call the Persons getter
```

The reason I ask is that the getter and setter to modify a `Person` for a given `Root` is quite complex and I´d like to avoid to call its getters for the sake of setting the properties for that `Person`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explicitly addressed in 7.6.10.2 of the C# Language Specification.

The standard gives this example for a "nested object initializer":

```
public class Point
{
    int x, y;
    public int X { get { return x; } set { x = value; } }
    public int Y { get { return y; } set { y = value; } }
}

public class Rectangle
{
    Point p1, p2;
    public Point P1 { get { return p1; } set { p1 = value; } }
    public Point P2 { get { return p2; } set { p2 = value; } }
}

Rectangle r = new Rectangle 
{
    P1 = new Point { X = 0, Y = 1 },
    P2 = new Point { X = 2, Y = 3 }
};
```

The standard says that this has the same effect as:

```
Rectangle __r = new Rectangle();
Point __p1 = new Point();
__p1.X = 0;
__p1.Y = 1;
__r.P1 = __p1;
Point __p2 = new Point();
__p2.X = 2;
__p2.Y = 3;
__r.P2 = __p2; 
Rectangle r = __r;
```

Here you can see that the `Rectangle.P1` and `Rectangle.P2` properties are initialised from already-created `Point` objects.

This proves that the answer to your question

> Is Person completely created and than assigned to the new instance of Root?

is definitively: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

We can easily check this out by setting a breakpoint within the getter for `Person` within the `Root`-class. When debugging we notice it´s never hit.

This indeed leads to the following object-graph being created:

```
var p = new Person();
p.Age = 20;
p.Name = "Hans";

var r = new Root();
r.Person = p;
```

You see no getter is accessed in order to set the persons properties because the `Person` is created *first*, before any `Root` even exists.

This ensures that the `Root` is completely created only if previously a `Person` has been completely created.