# Object Initialization can be simplified :IDE0017

Tags: c#, .net

With my code I get messages which shows messages as:

```
Object initialization can be simplified.
```

They are not shown as errors? How does simplification help? How do I simplify this code

```
        _passwordEntry = new Entry();
        _passwordEntry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Text;
        _passwordEntry.Placeholder = "Password";
        stackLayout.Children.Add(_passwordEntry);
```

Comment: These messages are not errors. For the advantages of direct object initialization vs your current code read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842371/is-there-any-benefit-of-using-an-object-initializer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Place your mouse over the green highlighted code in Visual Studio and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> or right click -> quick actions and refactoring.

Visual Studio will certainly offer you the possibility to change your code to this :

```
stackLayout.Children.Add(new Entry
{
    Keyboard = Keyboard.Text,
    Placeholder = "Password"
});
```

This is not an error, but an eventual simplification in code