# Use object initializer - Resharper suggestion

Tags: c#, optimization, resharper, object-initializers

I use `ReSharper` everyday, and today I asked myself why ReSharper suggests "Use object initializer" when I do this :

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.MyInt = 0;
myClass.MyString = string.Empty;
```

It gets replaced by :

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass
{
    MyInt = 0, 
    MyString = string.Empty
};
```

Does this optimize the execution of my code, or is it just a matter of reformatting?

Personally, I like it. But sometimes I hate it, because of this :

[image: Resharper]

I can't do `step-by-step` debugging :(

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The second contains less characters and so is more compact to read. You don't have to repeat myClass 2 more times, and the initialization logic is in one block.

It is really a syntactic sugar that doesn't change a thing in the generated code. If you doesn't like it, you can always disable the warning on ReSharper.

A longer post on the advantages of using Object Initializers here:

- [Setting properties via object initialization or not : Any difference ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973463/setting-properties-via-object-initialization-or-not-any-difference?lq=1)
- [Is there any benefit of using an Object Initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842371/is-there-any-benefit-of-using-object-initializer-in-c)

Comment: I may have the opposite opinion on its readability and feel that the unnecessary syntactic composition more easily leads to cluttered indecipherable code (after resharping we have a fun trend of chains of complex initializers in a single param list, blech), but this is a great answer, with further reading and addressing full question, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can do step-by-step debugging partially if initializers are function calls:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass() 
{
    MyInt = 3,
    MyString = GenerateString(9)
};
```

In this case, F11 will lead you straight into the GenerateString method.

EDIT: If initializers are simple values, then step-by-step debugging is meaningless anyway.